# Android, Json Parsing Error

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I am new to JSON and a relative beginner in Android, I have come across a problem which I have been unable to solve for several hours and am hoping the community can help.

The point of this application is get JSON Data and display it in a Custom Listview which will only show the thumbnail URL and title.

From what I am understanding it is a JSON parsing error that seems to stop for some reason, and hence when I try to call my custom listview to set it, I am passing in empty String Arrays since no data was filled during the JSON parse.

The error in question looks like this.

```
 E/Zygote: v2
 I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10010
 I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
 E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
 W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0005, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
 I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout 
 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
 D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaKeyStore is not enabled: cannot add TimaSignature Service and generateKeyPair Service
06-29 09:22:16.042 31340-31350/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
06-29 09:22:16.042 31340-31350/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
06-29 09:22:16.166 31340-31340/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout-1/lib/arm64
06-29 09:22:16.185 31340-31340/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
06-29 09:22:16.247 31340-31340/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-29 09:22:16.316 31340-31340/? D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-29 09:22:16.317 31340-31340/? D/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = com.samsung.android.hardware.context.ISemContextService$Stub$Proxy@ed99b7a
06-29 09:22:16.318 31340-31340/? D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a628f2b
06-29 09:22:16.318 31340-31340/? D/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.gesture.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@a628f2b
06-29 09:22:16.323 31340-31340/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-29 09:22:16.323 31340-31340/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout, PID: 31340
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout/com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
                                                       at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3826)
                                                       at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3813)
                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:139)
                                                       at com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout.CustomAdapter.<init>(CustomAdapter.java:0)
                                                       at com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
06-29 09:22:16.325 31340-31391/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-29 09:22:16.327 31340-31391/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-29 09:22:16.327 31340-31391/? I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-29 09:22:16.512 31340-31391/? E/MainActivity: Response from url: [
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 1,
                                                     "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/92c952",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/92c952"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 2,
                                                     "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/771796",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/771796"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 3,
                                                     "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/24f355",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/24f355"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 4,
                                                     "title": "culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/d32776",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/d32776"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 5,
                                                     "title": "natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/f66b97",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/f66b97"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 6,
                                                     "title": "accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/56a8c2",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/56a8c2"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 7,
                                                     "title": "officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/b0f7cc",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/b0f7cc"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 8,
                                                     "title": "aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/54176f",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/54176f"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 9,
                                                     "title": "qui eius qui autem sed",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/51aa97",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/51aa97"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 10,
                                                     "title": "beatae et provident et ut vel",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/810b14",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/810b14"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 11,
                                                     "title": "nihil at amet non hic quia qui",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/1ee8a4",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/1ee8a4"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 12,
                                                     "title": "mollitia soluta ut rerum eos aliquam consequatur perspiciatis maiores",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/66b7d2",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/66b7d2"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 13,
                                                     "title": "repudiandae iusto deleniti rerum",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/197d29",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/197d29"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 14,
                                                     "title": "est necessitatibus architecto ut laborum",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/61a65",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/61a65"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 15,
                                                     "title": "harum dicta similique quis dolore earum ex qui",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/f9cee5",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/f9cee5"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 16,
                                                     "title": "iusto sunt nobis quasi veritatis quas expedita voluptatum deserunt",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/fdf73e",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/fdf73e"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 17,
                                                     "title": "natus doloribus necessitatibus ipsa",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/9c184f",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/9c184f"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 18,
                                                     "title": "laboriosam odit nam necessitatibus et illum dolores reiciendis",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/1fe46f",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/1fe46f"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 19,
                                                     "title": "perferendis nesciunt eveniet et optio a",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/56acb2",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/56acb2"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "albumId": 1,
                                                     "id": 20,
                                                     "title": "assumenda voluptatem laboriosam enim consequatur veniam placeat reiciendis error",
                                                     "url": "http://placehold.it/600/8985dc",
                                                     "thumbnailUrl": "http://p
06-29 09:22:16.775 31340-31391/? E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value [{"albumId":1,"id":1,"title":"accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/92c952","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/92c952"},{"albumId":1,"id":2,"title":"reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/771796","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/771796"},{"albumId":1,"id":3,"title":"officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/24f355","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/24f355"},{"albumId":1,"id":4,"title":"culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/d32776","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/d32776"},{"albumId":1,"id":5,"title":"natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/f66b97","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/f66b97"},{"albumId":1,"id":6,"title":"accusamus ea aliquid et amet sequi nemo","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/56a8c2","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/56a8c2"},{"albumId":1,"id":7,"title":"officia delectus consequatur vero aut veniam explicabo molestias","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/b0f7cc","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/b0f7cc"},{"albumId":1,"id":8,"title":"aut porro officiis laborum odit ea laudantium corporis","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/54176f","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/54176f"},{"albumId":1,"id":9,"title":"qui eius qui autem sed","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/51aa97","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/51aa97"},{"albumId":1,"id":10,"title":"beatae et provident et ut vel","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/810b14","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/810b14"},{"albumId":1,"id":11,"title":"nihil at amet non hic quia qui","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/1ee8a4","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/1ee8a4"},{"albumId":1,"id":12,"title":"mollitia soluta ut rerum eos aliquam consequatur perspiciatis maiores","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/66b7d2","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/66b7d2"},{"albumId":1,"id":13,"title":"repudiandae iusto deleniti rerum","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/197d29","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/197d29"},{"albumId":1,"id":14,"title":"est necessitatibus architecto ut laborum","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/61a65","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/61a65"},{"albumId":1,"id":15,"title":"harum dicta similique quis dolore earum ex qui","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/f9cee5","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/f9cee5"},{"albumId":1,"id":16,"title":"iusto sunt nobis quasi veritatis quas expedita voluptatum deserunt","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/fdf73e","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/fdf73e"},{"albumId":1,"id":17,"title":"natus doloribus necessitatibus ipsa","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/9c184f","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/9c184f"},{"albumId":1,"id":18,"title":"laboriosam odit nam necessitatibus et illum dolores reiciendis","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/1fe46f","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/1fe46f"},{"albumId":1,"id":19,"title":"perferendis nesciunt eveniet et optio a","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/56acb2","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/56acb2"},{"albumId":1,"id":20,"title":"assumenda voluptatem laboriosam enim consequatur veniam placeat reiciendis error","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/8985dc","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/8985dc"},{"albumId":1,"id":21,"title":"ad et natus qui","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/5e12c6","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/5e12c6"},{"albumId":1,"id":22,"title":"et ea illo et sit voluptas animi blanditiis porro","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/45601a","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/45601a"},{"albumId":1,"id":23,"title":"harum velit vero totam","url":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/600\/e924e6","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150\/e924e6"},{"albumId":1,"id":24,"title":"beatae officiis ut aut","
```

My code is below as follows.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   String[] photoLast;
   String [] titleLast;
    ArrayList<String> urlPhoto = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> titleName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView jsonDisplay;
    CustomAdapter displayAdapter;

    final static String URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        new Read().execute();
        displayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,titleLast, photoLast);
        jsonDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonDisplay);
        jsonDisplay.setAdapter(displayAdapter);

//        jsonDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonDisplay);
//        displayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, title);
//        jsonDisplay.setAdapter(displayAdapter);
    }



    public class Read extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String url = URL;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);



            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if(jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray photos = json.getJSONArray("photos");
                    photoLast = new String[photos.length()];
                    titleLast = new String[photos.length()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject temp = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = temp.getString("title");
                        String thumbNailURL = temp.getString("thumbnailUrl");

                        photoLast[i]=thumbNailURL;
                        titleLast[i]=title;
//                        urlPhoto.add(thumbNailURL);
//                        titleName.add(title);

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error2: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                } else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
           //TODO Auto-Generated method stub
            //photoLast = urlPhoto.toArray(photoLast);
            //titleLast = titleName.toArray(titleLast);
             super.onPostExecute(result);


       }



    }
}
```

**HttpHandler** (past text limit need to remove, put in where I got code)

```
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
package com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout;

/**
 * Created by User on 6/29/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static com.example.user.remotemachineuilayout.R.id.url;


public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    //private final Activity context;
    private final String[] titleList;
    private final String[] urlList;



    public CustomAdapter(Context context1, String[] title, String[] url) {
        super(context1, R.layout.custom_row, title);
        //this.context = context1;
        this.titleList = title;
        this.urlList = url;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(url);

        txtTitle.setText(titleList[position]);
        Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(urlList[position]).into(imageView);


        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: first `new Read().execute();` is asynchronous and second, i can't see any  `photos` jsonarray in your response

Comment: Your right, and another user pointed that out as well. Thanks for the heads up, I have no idea why I even put a photos jsonarray

Comment: Clearly a null pointer exception. You are retrieving a value from a wrong name or the json does not contains what you want to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray photos = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            photoLast = new String[photos.length()];
            titleLast = new String[photos.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject temp = photos.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = temp.getString("title");
                String thumbNailURL = temp.getString("thumbnailUrl");

                photoLast[i]=thumbNailURL;
                titleLast[i]=title;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Try this code.
i can't see any json array called "photos"

Comment: Ah your right, I dont even know where I got those photos from? works perfectly now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Termination of app is because off NullPointerExection. AsyncTask runs on a different thread so

```
  new Read().execute();
        displayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,titleLast, photoLast);
        jsonDisplay = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonDisplay);
        jsonDisplay.setAdapter(displayAdapter);
```

when you use like that, titleLast and photoLast will be null. Moving last three lines to Read's onPostExecute function will resolve this problem.

Comment: Actually I had them there before and it still generated a Parsing Error, cut off at the same point